# Sum involving consecutive prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime number, $q$ any prime number and $m$ a positive integer $\geq 1$. For real positive $x$ define the set: $$T_m(x,q)=\left\{p_i\leqslant x;\operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{p_{i+1}-1}{q^m}\right) < \operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{p_i-1}{q^m}\right)\right\},$$
where $\operatorname{frac}(u)$ is the fractional part of $u$.

**Question:** how to estimate the sum $T(x,q)=\sum_{m\geq1}\lvert{T_m(x,q)\rvert}$, as ${x\to\infty}$, where $\lvert{T_m(x,q)\rvert}$ is the cardinality of the set $T_m(x,q)$?

Comment: To you have a justification for looking at such unnatural function of $p_i,p_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, $T(x,q)$  is the order of $q$ dividing product $\prod{p_{i+1}-1\choose p_i-1}$,   $p_i\leq x$

Comment: But $\prod{p_{i+1}-1\choose p_i-1}$ is not quite a natural thing to look at.

Comment: It is, via formula $N!=\prod({p_{i+1}-p_i})!\cdot\prod{p_{i+1}-1\choose p_i-1}$,  $p_i\leq N+1$, $p_0=1$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problen i can prove only:
**A)** Let $p_{i+1}-p_i=d_i$;  If $q>\max_{i}(d_i)$,than  $T(x,q)=\nu_{q}(N!)\approx\frac{N}{q-1}$ where $\nu_{q}(N!)$ is the order of $q$ dividing $N!$

**Proof:** From equality $N!=\prod_i(d_i)!\cdot\prod_i{p_{i+1}-1\choose p_i-1}$,  $p_0=1<p_1....<p_n= N+1$,  we can deduce $\nu_{q}(N!)=\sum_i\nu_q(d_i!)+\sum_mT_m(N,q)$, but  $\nu_q(d_i!)=0,0\leq{i}\leq{n-1}$, so A) follows.
**I have used:** $\nu_q\prod_i{p_{i+1}-1\choose p_i-1}=\sum_{i,m}([\frac{p_{i+1}-1}{q^m}]-[\frac{p_{i+1}-1}{q^m}]-[\frac{p_{i}-1}{q^m}])=\sum_{i,m}S_{i,m}$, but $S_{i,m}=1$ if $\frac{p_{i+1}-1}{q^m}<\frac{p_{i}-1}{q^m}$ and $0$ otherwise ($[u]$-is floor function)